# Intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras is not an algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following task:

> Give an example of two $\sigma$-algebras such that their intersection is not an algebra

There is a hint that such situation is possible only when their units differ, but I still can't come up to solution.

Let $S_1,S_2$ be our $\sigma$-algebras and $X = S_1 \cap S_2$.

1) $A,B \in X \Rightarrow A \setminus B \in X$. This is obvious because $A,B \in S_i \Rightarrow A \setminus B \in S_i$ (for $i=1,2$).

2) Similarly, $A,B \in X \Rightarrow A \cup B \in X$.

3) Similarly, any countable union is in $X$ too (though we do not need $X$ be a $\sigma$-ring by condition of the task).

So $X$ is at least a $\sigma$-ring and it must not contain a unit (or otherwise it will become an algebra).

If $X$ is countable, then union of all its elements $A = \bigcup A_i$ is contained in $X$. This easily makes $A$ a unit. Thus our $X$ must be uncountable. And from here I can neither prove that $X$ contains a unit nor disapprove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ and $X$ any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that $X$ doesn't belong $B$, consider two $\sigma$-algebras $B$ and $S = \{A\cap X \mid A\in B\}$. $X$ doesn't belong $B \cap S$, so $B \cap S$ doesn't contain universal set.

Comment: I think it is implicit that the two $\sigma$-algebras are supposed to be over the same universal set. So that universal set will be in both algebras and therefore in their intersecion.

Comment: If two sigma algebras have same universal set , then their intersection is sigma algebra too,

Comment: x @Anton: Indeed, so I would say the answer is "there is no such example". Though I suppose there's something to be said for interpreting the question such that it asks for something that is possible.

Comment: "There is a tip that such situation is possible only when their units differ"- Quotation from question

Comment: Fair enough, +1. Note, by the way, that this example depends on the axiom of choice for being sure there is a non-Borel set to choose in the first place. To avoid that we could take $S_1$ being the algebra of all countable or co-countable subsets of $\mathbb R$, and $S_2$ being $\mathcal P([0,1])$.